# Rails 5.1.4 console validate extra attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I have an issue when trying to use a console to make sure a record is valid. When I selected a record from the database and validate it, it says it's not valid, and when I check the model validators, it shows me extra attributes to be validated that I haven't specified on my model. If I tried on my development environment in the web, the same record validation is true. :(

Comment: Need a lot more detail here @helmutrs - we're going blind with this. Could you add the model code, at a minimum, please?

Comment: I've figured it out.. The thing was that those two attributes are "belong_to" objects, and by default those are required on Rails 5. I just need to put them as optional, and solve my issue. Thanks for you time though.

Comment: Glad to hear it - it's a common issue switching to Rails 5, I've been there myself :) By all means post an answer to your own question - might help someone else down the line.